# array as parameter when calling `rvs` or `pdf` on scipy.stats.rv_continuous

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am using `scipy.stats.rv_continuous` to create a random variable from a custom distribution. My distribution has many parameters which I might like to tweak, and event the number of parameters does not necessarily need to remain fixed. Here is what it looks like at the moment:

```
class Test_gen(rv_continuous):
    v = np.array([0.0, 0.1, 0.1])

    def _pdf(self, x):
        return 1.0/2/np.pi * (1 + np.sum(2 * self.v * np.cos(x)))

test = Test_gen(name='test', a=0, b=2*np.pi)
np.random.seed(42)
test.pdf(0)

>>> 0.22281692032865347
```

As you can see, I am consuming all the values in the `v` array to produce a single random variable - as expected. I am now trying to pass the `v` vector as a shape parameter when calling `test.pdf`. As far as I understand I would just add a `v` parameter to the `_pdf` function. However, since `v` is a vector, scipy thinks that I want to vectorize the call to produce several random variables at once. It therefore tries to broadcast my given argument and produces a result which I cannot quite understand where it comes from. Here is a non-working example:

```
class Test_gen(rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self, x, v):
        print "Got `v` as: ", v
        return 1.0/2/np.pi * (1 + np.sum(2 * v * np.cos((x ))))

test = Test_gen(name='test', a=0, b=2*np.pi)
np.random.seed(42)

test.pdf(0, v=np.array([0, 0.1, 0.1]))

>>> Got `v` as:  [ 0.1  0.1]
>>> array([        nan,  0.22281692,  0.22281692])
```

I would expect the latter example to produce `0.22281692032865347` (as a scalar) just like the first example. How can I use vectors as parameters if I intent to have them all consumed to produce a single variable?

Comment: It looks like the ``pdf()`` method of ``rv_continuous`` assumes that all parameters are scalars and should be broadcast together (see the code [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py#L1623)). I don't know of a way to allow vector parameters, unfortunately. Probably the easiest way would be to override the ``pdf()`` function so that it handles your vector parameter correctly, though that will take a bit of work.